# pct_change between non-adjacent pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the pct_change in a Pandas series but not in the regular way in which changes are calculated between adjacent elements, but within elements two places apart.

For instance:

```
pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
dtype: int64
```

Compare `1` with `4`, `2` with `5`, `3` with `6` and `4` with `7` (strides of 3).

Comment: So they are always `n_steps=3` away?

Comment: Yes, it is always the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `periods` parameter in [`pd.Series.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html#pandas-series-pct-change):

```
s.pct_change(periods=3)
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    3.00
4    1.50
5    1.00
6    0.75
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(1,10))
n_steps = 3

s.groupby(np.arange(len(s))%n_steps).pct_change()
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    3.00
4    1.50
5    1.00
6    0.75
7    0.60
8    0.50
dtype: float64
```